# How to handle failure cases in C++ class constructor?

Tags: object-oriented, c++

I have a CPP class whose constructor does some operations. Some of these operations may fail. I know that constructors do not return anything.

My questions are,

1. Is it allowed to do some operations other that initializing members in a constructor?
2. Is it possible to tell the calling function that some operations in constructor has been failed?
3. Can I make `new ClassName()` return NULL if some errors occur in constructor?

Comment: You can throw an exception from within the constructor. It's a completely valid pattern.

Comment: You probably should have a look at some of the [creational patterns of the GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). I recommend the factory pattern.

Comment: A common example of #1 is data validation. IE if you have a class `Square`, with a constructor that takes one parameter, the length of a side, you want to check if that value is greater than 0.

Comment: For the first question, let me warn you that virtual functions can behave unintuitively in constructors. Same with deconstructors. Beware calling such.

Comment: #3 - Why would you want to return a NULL?  One of the benefits of OO is NOT having to check return values.  Just catch() the appropriate potential exceptions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Yes, though some coding standards may prohibit it.
2. Yes. The recommended way is to throw an exception. Alternatively, you can store the error information inside the object and provide methods to access this information.
3. No.

Comment: Unless the object is still in valid state even though some part of the constructor arguments did not meet requirements and thus is marked as an error, 2) is really not recommended to do. It is better when an object either exists in a valid state or does not exist at all.

Comment: @DavidPacker Agreed, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639/when-is-it-right-for-a-constructor-to-throw-an-exception/77705#77705 But some coding guidelines prohibit exceptions, which is problematic for constructors.

Comment: Somehow I have already given you an upvote for that answer, Sebastian. Interesting. :D

Comment: While I'm not a C++ expert, I disagree with 3). Shouldn't it be possible to override `new` to handle failure and return null?

Comment: @ooxi No, it's not. Your overridden new is called to allocate memory, but the call to the constructor is done by the compiler after your operator has returned, which means you don't get to catch the error. That's assuming new is called at all; it isn't for stack-allocated objects, which should be most of them.

Comment: A note about #2: something similar is used in Qt code to report errors.  Many Qt objects have an `isNull` method to see if the object is valid.  [See the QString docs for an example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#isNull)

Comment: For #1, RAII is a common example where doing more in the constructor may be required.

Comment: @KarlNicoll No, `new (nothrow)` will return null on memory allocation failure, but exceptions from the constructor will still propagate normally.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - Yep you're absolutely right, good spot. I had always assumed that `std::nothrow` covered all exceptions and not just `std::bad_alloc` within `new()`. I've removed my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 23):

You could create a static method that performs the calculation and returns either an object in case of success or not case of failure.

Depending on how this construction of the object is done, it might be better to create another object that allows construction of objects in a non static method.

Calling a constructor indirectly is often referred to as a "factory".

This would also allow you to return a null-object, which might be a better solution than returning null.

Comment: Thank you @null! Unfortunately can not accept two answers here :( Otherwise I would have accepted this answer too!! Thanks again!

Comment: @MayurK no worries, the accepted answer is not to mark *the* correct answer, but the one that worked for you.

Comment: `std::optional<T>` is still one year away (C++17), so until then it's not so simple for your method to either return an object or not. Up to C++14, `T foo()` returns a T object and `void foo()` does not return an object.

Comment: @MSalters I thout it's obvious from the context of the question that by *returning no object* I was referring to returning `NULL`. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I think your comment should be an answer itself, even though it will only be possible the future. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @null: In C++, you can't just return `NULL`. For instance, in `int foo() { return NULL` you would actually return `0` (zero), an integer object. In `std::string foo() { return NULL; }` you'd accidentally call `std::string::string((const char*)NULL)` which is Undefined Behavior (NULL does not point to a \0-terminated string).

Comment: @MSalters yeah right, too much java lately.

Comment: std::optional may be a way away but you could always use boost::optional if you wanted to go that way.

Comment: @SeanBurton: or `boost::variant` (since `std::variant` is not there yet either) if you want to return a more meaningful error than "it failed".

Comment: @MSalters if we're talking about _objects_, especially things that have _constructors_ we aren't talking about `int`. A factory method or class should be producing objects, I would have thought. Unless you have factory for primitives?

Comment: @Vld: In C++, _objects_ aren't restricted to class types. And with generic programming, it's not uncommon to end up with factories for `int`. E.g. `std::allocator<int>` is a perfectly sane factory.

Answer (score 5):

@SebastianRedl already gave the simple, direct answers, but some extra explanation might be useful.

TL;DR = there's a style rule to keep constructors simple, there's reasons for it, but those reasons mostly relate to a historic (or simply bad) style of coding. Handling of exceptions in constructors is well defined, and destructors will still be called for fully-constructed local variables and members, which means there shouldn't be any problems in idiomatic C++ code. The style rule persists anyway, but normally that's not a problem - not all initialization has to be in the constructor, and particularly not necessarily that constructor.

---

It's a common **style rule** that constructors should do the absolute minimum they can to set up a defined valid state. If your initialization is more complex, it should be handled outside the constructor. If there's no cheap-to-initialize value that your constructor can set up, you should weaken the invarants enforced by your class to add one. For example if allocating storage for your class to manage is too expensive, add a not-allocated-yet null state, because of course having special-case states like null never caused anyone any problems. Ahem.

Although common, certainly in this extreme form it's very far from absolute. In particular, as my sarcasm indicates, I'm in the camp that says weakening invariants is almost always too high a price. However, there are reasons behind the style rule, and there's ways to have both minimal constructors *and* strong invariants.

The reasons relate to automatic destructor cleanup, particularly in the face of exceptions. Basically, there has to be a well-defined point when the compiler becomes responsible for calling destructors. While you're still in a constructor call, the object isn't necessarily fully constructed, so it's not valid to call the destructor for that object. Therefore, the responsibility for destructing the object only transfers to the compiler when the constructor successfully completes. This is known as RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialization) which isn't really the best name.

If an exception throw occurs inside the constructor, anything part-constructed needs to be explicitly cleaned up, typically in a `try .. catch`.

However, *components* of the object which have already successfully constructed are already the compilers responsibility. This means that in practice, it's not really a big deal. e.g.

```
classname (args) : base1 (args), member2 (args), member3 (args)
{
}
```

The body of this constructor is empty. So long as the constructors for `base1`, `member2` and `member3` are exception safe, there's nothing to worry about. For example, if the constructor of `member2` throws, that constructor is responsible for cleaning itself up. The base `base1` was already completely constructed, so its destructor will be automatically called. `member3` was never even partially constructed, so doesn't need cleanup.

Even when there's a body, local variables that were fully constructed before the exception was thrown will be automatically destructed, just like any other function. Constructor bodies that juggle raw pointers, or "own" some kind of implicit state (stored elsewhere) - typically meaning a begin/acquire function call must be matched to an end/release call - can cause exception safety problems, but the real problem there is failing to manage a resource properly via a class. For example if you replace raw pointers with `unique_ptr` in the constructor, the destructor for `unique_ptr` will be called automatically if needed.

There's still other reasons people give for preferring do-the-minimum constructors. One is simply because the style rule exists, many people assume constructor calls are cheap. One way to have that, yet still have strong invariants, is to have a separate factory/builder class that has the weakened invariants instead, and which sets up the needed initial value using (potentially many) normal member-function calls. Once you have the initial state you need, pass that object as an argument to the constructor for the class with the strong invariants. That can "steal the guts" of the weak-invariants object - move semantics - which is a cheap (and usually `noexcept`) operation.

And of course you can wrap that in a `make_whatever ()` function, so callers of that function never need to see the weakened-invariants class instance.

Comment: The paragraph where you write "While you're still in a constructor call, the object isn't necessarily fully constructed, so it's not valid to call the destructor for that object. Therefore, the responsibility for destructing the object only transfers to the compiler when the constructor successfully completes" could really use an update concerning delegating constructors.  The object is fully constructed when any most-derived constructor finished, and the destructor *will* be called if an exception occurs inside a delegating constructor.

Comment: Thus, the "do-the-minimum" constructor can be private, and the "make_whatever()" function can be another constructor that calls the private one.

Comment: This is not the definition of RAII I am familiar with.  My understanding of RAII is to intentionally acquire a resource in (and only in) an object's constructor and release it in its destructor.  In this way, the object can be used on the stack to automatically manage acquisition and release of the resources it encapsulates.  The classic example is a lock that acquires a mutex when constructed and releases it on destruction.

Comment: @Ben - I'm vaguely aware that constructors can call other constructors now, but I've never done that yet and I hadn't even thought about the implications. I assume by "most-derived" you mean constructor for this actual class (not a base), and "any most-derived constructor finished" usually means the deepest+earliest in the call graph. I'll update once I'm reasonably sure I understand.

Comment: @Eric - That's the origin of the acronym, but it's misleading (as Stroustrup has said). Resources need not be acquired during construction, or even during vaguely-defined "initialization". The policy is that resources should always be owned by an object which takes responsibility for freeing them in its destructor. But as that can't be true when the constructor hasn't yet completed, the key aspect is when the compiler becomes responsible for calling the destructor. That's how the policy translates to things the language knows about directly, so that's what RAII tends to mean in practice.

Comment: @Eric - Incidentally, what is a resource? In practice, at least in C++, anything that requires some kind of cleanup when you're finished with it. How you get the resource is almost beside the point. "Initialization" is a subjective term - something that programmers know (and sometimes disagree) about, but beyond constructors, the language and compiler don't know or care. The important points are when ownership transfers, and when destructors are called.

Comment: @Steve314 I think you are stretching the definition of RAII beyond the breaking point. Transferring ownership of resources to an object at an arbitrary point in its lifecycle is not RAII. Relegating clean up of owned resources to the destructor is standard practice and not specific to RAII. To me RAII is about linking ownership of a resource by an object to that object's lifecycle and generally using such objects on the stack instead of the heap.

Comment: @Eric - Yes, it's absolutely standard practice - a standard practice which is commonly called RAII. It's not just me that stretches the definition - it's even Stroustrup, in some talks. Yes, RAII is about linking linking resource lifecycles to object lifecycles, the mental model being ownership.

Comment: @Eric - previous replies deleted because they were explained badly. Anyway, objects themselves are resources that can be owned. Everything *should* have an owner, in a chain right up to the `main` function or static/global variables. An object allocated using `new`, *isn't* owned until you assign that responsibility, but smart pointers own the heap-allocated objects they reference, and containers own their data structures. Owners can choose to delete early, the owners destructor is ultimately responsible.

Comment: @Eric - if you really want to quibble about ownership and stack, in the case where the owner is a function invocation (the object is a local variable on the stack), the owner isn't an object - it's the compilers responsibility rather than a destructors (to call the destructor). Something similar for static/global variables - its not clear what the owner is, but what owns the object isn't the object itself - it doesn't even own its own memory (e.g. doesn't know if its static/stack/heap allocated).

Answer (score 0):

Use factory functions.

Constructors, destructors, and the other 'special functions' of c++ classes are really 2nd class citizens of the language. They aren't proper functions. You can't get pointers to them, they don't have proper returns, and the logic you're allowed to invoke inside them has all sorts of special rules & syntax- no throws from a destructor, assignment operators must return "this",etc.

In your case you need a normal function that will return a new object on success or a null on failure. The easiest way to do this for class 'X' is to have a plain old static member function of 'X' that returns a std::unique<X>  or (for stack allocation) std::optional<X>. If you want to return error information on error instead of nothing & have support for bleeding-edge C++, you could even use std::expected<X, E> where 'E' is the return type for errors.

The major advantages of factory functions is that they're 1st class, true functions. So you can take their address, feed them into std::invoke, etc. If you want to be REALLY clever, you can template the factory on the concrete class type and require each concrete class to provide its potentially-failing setup/initialization logic in a virtual API (e.g. "virtual bool initialize();"). The factory then becomes a static member of the base, interface class 'X' like so:

```
   class X {
       private: // So only the factory can call it 
           virtual bool initialize() = 0; 

       public:
           template <class Y, typename... Args> 
              requires std::derived_from<Y, X>
           static std::unique_ptr<Y> create(Args&&... paramsToCtor) 
           {
                std::unique_ptr<Y> out = std::make_unique<Y>(std::forward<Args>(paramsToCtor...));
                if(out->initialize()) {
                    return out;
                }
                return nullptr;
           }
   };

   struct SomeThing : public X {
      friend X::create<SomeThing, const std::string&>; // Our class, each constructor's parameters 
      friend X::create<SomeThing, int>;
      private: // So only the (base class) factory will invoke it 
         virtual bool initialize() override { /*Setup logic that can fail*/ }
      protected: // So only derived classes can directly call these 
         SomeThing(const std::string& example); // Example constructors. 
         SomeThing(int alternateCtor); 
      public: 
         // The actual interface external users of 'SomeThing' should see

   };

   // User creates a 'Something' with the factory
   // 'ptr' might be null
   std::unique_ptr<SomeThing> ptr = X::create<SomeThing>("test");

   // User tries to call constructor directly => compile error 
   SomeThing* rawPtr = new SomeThing("will not compile");
```

This is likely overkill for your needs, but it is a useful pattern for refactoring an entire set of related classes to use a factory function.